# Compile PHP extension using SWIG on Windows

Tags: php, c++, visual-studio, swig

I'd like to create a PHP wrapper for an existing C++ library. I found a tutorial online that uses gcc but I'd like to do the same thing using the Visual Studio command line on windows. 
I started doing this:

```
swig -php example.i
```

Which worked well. Then I have to build the created wrappers as an extension. The SWIG tutorial suggests the following:

```
gcc `php-config --includes` -fpic -c example_wrap.c
gcc -shared example_wrap.o -o example.so
```

What is the VS equivalent to those two calls? I'd use *cl* and *link* instead of *gcc* obviously but what to put instead of 'php-config --includes'? The VS command prompt does not recognize the php-config command as well as the '--'.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

The section of that command enclosed in backticks isn't a gcc argument, per se. The expression in the backticks is evaluated by the shell, and then that expression (including the backticks) is replaced by its result before actually being executed.

In this case, `php-config --includes` gives the arguments gcc needs to include all the appropriate php-related headers. On my install, the result is:

```
I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
```

That won't necessarily be valid for your computer. Just run `php-config --includes` to get what you what you need, take that output, and put it in the place of the `'php-config --includes'` in the example you found.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that but the command php-config is not found from within the VS command prompt.